# Switch Statement contains multiple cases with same label value, except it doesn't

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement, syntax-error, visual-studio-2019

I have this enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum
{
    NegativeValue = -1,
    Value0 = 0,
    Value1 = 2 ^ 1,
    Value2 = 2 ^ 2,
    Value3 = 2 ^ 3,
    Value4 = 2 ^ 4
}
```

Now I want to use a switch on this enum:

```
public void SwitchThroughEnum(MyEnum myEnum)
{
    switch (myEnum)
    {
        case MyEnum.NegativeValue:
            break;
        case MyEnum.Value0:
            break;
        case MyEnum.Value1:
            break;
        case MyEnum.Value2:
            break;
        case MyEnum.Value3:
            break;
        case MyEnum.Value4:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

But I can't compile this, because Visual Studio tells me that "The switch statement contains multiple cases with the label value '0'". I don't know why it does that.

[image]

EDIT: Is there any possibility to create the enum in a way to just use the power of 1, 2 etc? I sometimes have enums with way more then 30 entries, and calculating and writing the numbers is time killing

Comment: Why do you say 2^2 isn't 0? I think you've got some operators [confused](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-exclusive-or-operator-)

Comment: May be. I wanted to write 2 to the power of 2, and the character for that normally is ^

Comment: Normally? I've just checked and as well as C#, Java and C++ also use `^` for bitwise exclusive or. So what "normal" are you coming from?

Comment: I never used xor in C#, i mean normally like in googling or just chatting with others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I sometimes have enums with way more then 30 entries, and calculating
> and writing the numbers is time killing

Yeah, just [bit shift](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#left-shift-operator-).

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum
{
    NegativeValue = -1,
    Value0 = 0,
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2 << 0,
    Value3 = 2 << 1,
    Value4 = 2 << 2
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using the [Logical exclusive OR operator ^](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-or-operator-) not raising a number to a power.

C# doesn't have a power operator, and you can't use `Math.Pow` as it's not a constant and well, it returns a `double`.

Maybe you want binary literals instead:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    NegativeValue = -1,
    Value0 = 0,
    Value1 = 0b0000001,
    Value2 = 0b0000010,
    Value3 = 0b0000100,
    Value4 = 0b0001000,
}
```

Or

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    NegativeValue = -1,
    Value0 = 0,
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2,
    Value3 = 4,
    Value4 = 8,
}
```

Comment: The first one really helps me for big enums, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is the boolean XOR operator [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-exclusive-or-operator-)

> Exclusive or or exclusive disjunction is a logical operation that outputs true only when inputs differ (one is true, the other is false)

So the `2 ^ 2` is indeed 0

> The ^ operator computes the bitwise logical exclusive OR, also known as the bitwise logical XOR, of its integral operands.

So in bit logic `10 XOR 10 = 0`

My guess is that you want to use the power of 2 on 2, so why don't you do it directly?

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum
{
    NegativeValue = -1,
    Value0 = 0,
    Value1 = 2,
    Value2 = 4,
    Value3 = 8,
    Value4 = 16
}
```